# Non-functional JavaScript

Tags: jquery, html, css

First time programmer here.  I'm having trouble with a bit of jQuery I'm trying to add to a website I'm building.  I can't find the issue with my code, but when I click on the relevant link, the only thing it does is add a # to the end of the URL.  What am I missing here?

Thanks.  Code follows.

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.ShowHideButton').click(function(){
    $('.MenuBar').slideToggle('slow');
});
});
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="NavMenu.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="common.css">

<title>Test Room, North Wall</title>

<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="Icons/Favicon.PNG" type="image/x-icon" /> 

</head>
```

```
<div class="Wall">
    <img src="Rooms/NorthBlank.JPG" width = 100% />
</div>

<div class="Tray">
    <div class="SlideBar">
        <div class="ShowHideButton">
            <a href = "#"><img src="Icons/Toggle.png" /></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="MenuBar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href = "TestWest.htm"><img src="Icons/NavLeft.png" /></a></li>
            <li><img src="Icons/Info.PNG" /></li>
            <li><a href = "TestDoor.htm"><img src="Icons/Door.PNG" /></a></li>
            <li><a href = "TestEast.htm"><img src="Icons/NavRight.png" /></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
head{
font-family: Tahoma;
}

body {
font-family: Tahoma;
background-color: Black;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}

li {
display: inline;
}

.Wall {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
border: none;
position: fixed;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
}

.Tray {
width: 100%;
height: 150 px;
position: fixed;
bottom: 0px;
}

.MenuBar {
height: 150px;
width: 600px;
bottom: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
background-color: #999999;
opacity: 0.6;
}

.SlideBar {
width: 100%;
height: 150 px;
position: relative;
bottom: 0px;
}

.ShowHideButton {
height: 16px;
width: 90px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
background-color: #999999;
opacity: 0.6;
}
```

Comment: Apart from the missing jQuery library, I suggest you also learn how to debug in your browser (preferably Chrome or Firefox's firebug).

Comment: @ShadowScripter - good suggestion; not sure that would have helped in this instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the fact you haven't included jQuery (which [Jay Blanchard flagged up](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16522781/157247)), you also need to prevent the default action of the link:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.ShowHideButton').click(function(){
    $('.MenuBar').slideToggle('slow');
    return false; // <== The new bit
});
});
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.ShowHideButton').click(function(e){ // <== Added 'e' arg
    $('.MenuBar').slideToggle('slow');
    e.preventDefault();                 // <== And preventDefault call
});
});
```

This is because otherwise, clicking the link will follow the `href`, which in your case is `#` (hence the reason it got added to the URL).

Comment: Note that the `.ShowHideButton` is a div, not a link. Change to `.ShowHideButton a`.

Comment: @ShadowScripter The event propagates when the anchor is clicked, and triggers the above, so using `preventDefault()` on it is fine.

Comment: @ShadowScripter: No need, it prevents the default if you click the link even though I'm handling the event on the button, and this way it keeps doing what the OP wants (responding even if you click on some edge of the button that isn't the link).

Answer (score 2):

You haven't included the jQuery library. Here is one way to do it -

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And of course this should be linked PRIOR to your other Javascript code file link.

Answer (score 1):

You should also use `preventDefault()` to prevent the anchor from being followed once it has been clicked:

```
$('.ShowHideButton').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.MenuBar').slideToggle('slow');
});
```